# phonegap build how to open ios link in safari

Tags: cordova

I wrote this line in order to open link in safari,

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

but still, the link is opening in the application,
anyone knows why?

Comment: Did you add inAppBrowser API?

Comment: sure, i added to config xml this line:  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" /> @NijilNair

Comment: can you check if the source file of InAppBrowser plugin is included in the build phases of your XCode target?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues a time ago. I got it solved by checking the `access` tag in `config.xml` file. This entry contains the whitelist of the application, which means everything written in the `origin` attribute will be displayed in the Cordova WebView.
Maybe this helps for you, too.